# Finding Records if a field is used more than once in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

I am just trying to create a report that will give me the Job Numbers if the same address is being used for multiple Jobs.

E.g. if Jobs J1,J2 have same information for the field Job Address, I just need to pull those two Records.

Grouping by job Number helps but it also gives the valid Jobs which have the distinct Job Address.

Any help will be much appreciated . :)))

Comment: The quick and dirty way is to group by Job Address and suppress any where `distinctcount({Job.JobNumber},{Job.JobAddress})<2`

Comment: Hey Ryan, I think it works pretty well. You mentioned it a 'dirty way' have you seen any issues with this method ?

Comment: The issue is that it alters the format a little too much for my liking and doesn't really filter records from the DB perspective. But, if it works for you, then I wouldn't worry about it.